# Postgresql as docker container not starting with data from mapped volume

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

On my macbook I have postgresql running in a docker container and I use a mapped volume to persist the data. This works perfectly locally. However, when I try to do the same on the Ubuntu server the 'initial' data from the mapped volume is not working. Postgres starts up in an 'empty' initial state. 
However, when I add a table and data in that table in the default postgres database it IS persistent. So the volume mapping seems to work. 
Furthermore it is interesting to note that I'm getting an error when I try to create a table in a new database. The new database is persistent as well, but the table cant be saved as there is an error thrown:

> could not open file "base/16384/2611": No such file or directory

This is expected as the folder base/16384 doesn't exist.

To me this seems this is a user/rights issue perhaps, but no clue how to fix this. 
I tried running the container as root, which didn't help.

Any suggestions?

I'm starting the container with either docker-compose or from the command line using;

```
docker run --rm --name pg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[password] -d -p 5432:5432 -v /root/docker/volumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres -c listen_addresses='*'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of moving the actual data folder around I used pg_dump and pg_restore within the docker containers per [suggestion on the docker forums](https://forums.docker.com/t/postgresql-as-docker-container-not-starting-with-initial-data-from-mapped-volume/91284/3). This did the trick